# How to add a Scheffe Test to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m new in R and I taught it myself so please be indulgent with me :)

I want to include the Scheffe-Test to my ggplot. I have tried with the T-Test and the Anova that worked for me. Now that I want to change it to a Scheffe-Test doesnt work for me anymore. For me the reason seems to be the missing group1 and group2 columns but I don´t know how to add them. Can anybody help?
I will try to give an minimal working example:

My library:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(gtsummary)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(ggplot2)
library(DescTools)
```

The data:

```
> data_clean_bef_tbl
# A tibble: 11 × 3
   time   TEER Assay 
   <fct> <dbl> <fct> 
 1 -7      182 before
 2 -7      194 before
 3 -4      182 before
 4 -4      190 before
 5 -4      219 before
 6 0       241 before
 7 0       271 before
 8 0       246 before
 9 3       247 before
10 3       284 before
11 3       259 before
```

The ggplot:

```
ggplot_vor <- ggplot(data_clean_bef_tbl, aes(x = time, y = TEER)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = time),
               outlier.shape = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFF176", "#AED581", "#4DB6AC", "#7986CB")) +
  xlab("Seeding time of HT29-MTX-E12 cells compared to Caco-2 cells [days]") +
  ylab("TEER [Ω*qcm]") +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(shape=time),
             position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  stat_summary(fun="mean", fun.min = "min", fun.max = "max", 
               color = "#D32F2F") +
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 410)
```

The Anova- and Scheffe-Test:

```
anova_bef <- aov(TEER ~ time, data_clean_bef_tbl)
summary(anova_bef)
ScheffeTest(anova_bef, group = TRUE)
```

The T-Test that works fine for me:

```
stat_ttest_vor <- data_clean_bef_tbl %>%
  t_test(TEER ~ time, var.equal = FALSE) %>% 
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
  add_significance("p.adj") %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "time", dodge = 0.8)
```

ggplot + t-test + Anova

```
Boxplot_vor <- ggplot_vor +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat_ttest_vor,
                     label = "p.adj.signif",
                     step.increase = 0.02) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 410)
Boxplot_vor
```

[ggplot with Anova and T-test, but I want the same with the Scheffe-Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYFB8.png)

When I try the same with this code:

```
Boxplot_vor <- ggplot_vor +
  stat_pvalue_manual(Scheffe_bef,
                     label = "pval",
                     step.increase = 0.02) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1))) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 410)
Boxplot_vor
```

I get the error message:

> Error in asserttat_group_columns_exists(data) :    data should contain
> group1 and group2 columns

I´ve tried to add group1 and group2 columns manually to the Scheffe-test but since it´s not a tibble, this isn´t as easy as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be using the `Plot2WayANOVA` function from the `CGPfunctions`, [documenation](https://ibecav.github.io/CGPfunctions/reference/Plot2WayANOVA.html). First of all you should have to classes in your Assay column, so I added some random values for "after" class. According to the documentation this function:

> Takes a formula and a dataframe as input, conducts an analysis of
> variance prints the results (AOV summary table, table of overall model
> information and table of means) then uses ggplot2 to plot an
> interaction graph (line or bar) . Also uses Brown-Forsythe test for
> homogeneity of variance. Users can also choose to save the plot out as
> a png file.

Where you have the argument `potshot.method` where you can use the Scheffe test:

> A character string, one of "hsd", "bonf", "lsd", "scheffe",
> "newmankeuls", defining the method for the pairwise comparisons.
> (Default: `"scheffe"`).

The output of this function returns:

> A list with 5 elements which is returned invisibly. These items are
> always sent to the console for display but for user convenience the
> function also returns a named list with the following items in case
> the user desires to save them or further process them - $ANOVATable,
> $ModelSummary, $MeansTable, $PosthocTable, $BFTest, and $SWTest. The
> plot is always sent to the default plot device

So you can check in the $Posthoctable your results of the Scheffe test. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
data_clean_bef_tbl <- read.table(text="   time   TEER Assay 
 -7      182 before
 -7      194 before
 -4      182 before
 -4      190 before
 -4      219 before
 0       241 before
 0       271 before
 0       246 before
 3       247 before
 3       284 before
 3       259 before
 -7      183 after
 -7      195 after
 -4      186 after
 -4      192 after
 -4      216 after
 0       242 after
 0       274 after
 0       246 after
 3       248 after
 3       283 after
 3       252 after", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(CGPfunctions)
library(DescTools)
library(pwr)
anova_bef <- aov(TEER ~ time, data_clean_bef_tbl)
summary(anova_bef)
#>             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#> time         1  20920   20920   72.94 4.18e-08 ***
#> Residuals   20   5736     287                     
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
Plot2WayANOVA(TEER ~ time*Assay, 
              data = data_clean_bef_tbl, 
              xlab = "Seeding time of HT29-MTX-E12 cells compared to Caco-2 cells [days]",
              ylab = "TEER [Ω*qcm]",
              plottype = "bar", 
              posthoc.method = "scheffe",
              overlay.type = "box",
              ggplot.component = theme_minimal())
#> 
#> Converting time to a factor --- check your results
#> 
#> Converting Assay to a factor --- check your results
#> 
#>              --- WARNING! ---
#>      You have one or more cells with less than 3 observations.
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   time  Assay  count
#>   <fct> <fct>  <int>
#> 1 -7    after      2
#> 2 -7    before     2
#> 3 -4    after      3
#> 4 -4    before     3
#> 5 0     after      3
#> 6 0     before     3
#> 7 3     after      3
#> 8 3     before     3
#> 
#>              --- WARNING! ---
#>      You have an unbalanced design. Using Type II sum of 
#>             squares, to calculate factor effect sizes eta and omega.
#>             Your two factors account for 0.851 of the type II sum of 
#>             squares.
#> term       |     sumsq |   meansq | df | statistic | p.value | etasq | partial.etasq | omegasq | partial.omegasq | epsilonsq | cohens.f | power
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> time       | 22665.697 | 7555.232 |  3 |    26.594 |  < .001 | 0.850 |         0.851 |   0.810 |           0.777 |     0.818 |    2.387 | 1.000
#> Assay      |     0.182 |    0.182 |  1 |     0.001 |   0.980 | 0.000 |         0.000 |  -0.011 |          -0.048 |    -0.011 |    0.007 | 0.050
#> time:Assay |    13.152 |    4.384 |  3 |     0.015 |   0.997 | 0.000 |         0.003 |  -0.031 |          -0.155 |    -0.031 |    0.058 | 0.053
#> Residuals  |  3977.333 |  284.095 | 14 |           |         |       |               |         |                 |           |          |
#> 
#> Table of group means
#> # A tibble: 8 × 15
#> # Groups:   time [4]
#>   time  Assay  TheMean TheSD TheSEM CIMuliplier LowerBoundCI UpperBoundCI
#>   <fct> <fct>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 -7    after     189   8.49   6          12.7          113.         265.
#> 2 -7    before    188   8.49   6          12.7          112.         264.
#> 3 -4    after     198  15.9    9.17        4.30         159.         237.
#> 4 -4    before    197  19.5   11.2         4.30         149.         245.
#> 5 0     after     254  17.4   10.1         4.30         211.         297.
#> 6 0     before    253. 16.1    9.28        4.30         213.         293.
#> 7 3     after     261  19.2   11.1         4.30         213.         309.
#> 8 3     before    263. 18.9   10.9         4.30         216.         310.
#> # … with 7 more variables: LowerBoundSEM <dbl>, UpperBoundSEM <dbl>,
#> #   LowerBoundSD <dbl>, UpperBoundSD <dbl>, N <int>, LowerBound <dbl>,
#> #   UpperBound <dbl>
#> 
#> Post hoc tests for all effects that were significant
#> 
#>   Posthoc multiple comparisons of means: Scheffe Test 
#>     95% family-wise confidence level
#> 
#> $time
#>            diff    lwr.ci    upr.ci   pval    
#> -4--7  9.000000 -38.85861  56.85861 0.9976    
#> 0--7  64.833333  16.97473 112.69194 0.0048 ** 
#> 3--7  73.666667  25.80806 121.52527 0.0015 ** 
#> 0--4  55.833333  13.02729  98.63937 0.0067 ** 
#> 3--4  64.666667  21.86063 107.47271 0.0018 ** 
#> 3-0    8.833333 -33.97271  51.63937 0.9958    
#> 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Testing Homogeneity of Variance with Brown-Forsythe
#> Brown-Forsythe Test for Homogeneity of Variance using median
#>       Df F value Pr(>F)
#> group  7  0.0859 0.9984
#>       14
#> 
#> Testing Normality Assumption with Shapiro-Wilk
#>    *** Possible violation of the assumption.  You may 
#>             want to plot the residuals to see how they vary from normal ***
#> 
#>  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
#> 
#> data:  MyAOV_residuals
#> W = 0.83071, p-value = 0.001577
#> 
#> Bayesian analysis of models in order
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   model                            bf support                    margin_of_error
#>   <chr>                         <dbl> <chr>                                <dbl>
#> 1 time                      82116.    " data support is extreme"     0.000000283
#> 2 time + Assay              32418.    " data support is extreme"     0.0270     
#> 3 time + Assay + time:Assay  9663.    " data support is extreme"     0.0129     
#> 4 Assay                         0.385 " data support is anecdot…     0.0000144
#> 
#> Interaction graph plotted...
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I don´t think this is how I would like it to have. I want the exact same plot as I posted it but the significance braces are labelled with the Scheffe test instead of the t-test. That is the only difference.